# .NET CORE 2.1 app added to Linux(ARM) deamon cause CPU high

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, .net-core, debian

I'm using [RaspberryPi (3B+)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) Linux ARM IOT board which OS is [Debian Stretch 9](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), and my console application is developed on **.NET CORE 2.1**.

My application is quite simple by just open several TCP connections to a remote server, after build my application (with symbol `Linux ARM`), I can see the output files include `myApp`, and `myApp.dll`. I've done lots of run via directly command line:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/myApp $ ./myApp
```

or:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/myApp $ dotnet ./myApp.dll
```

which both runs well, and the CPU via `top` (process name is `myApp`, while the latter is `dotnet`) are **all less than 20**.

Today I want to add my app to **daemon** for keep runing all the way, this is my *daemon serivce* file under `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=myApp for controlling Tcp devices

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Desktop/myApp
# 
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dotnet myApp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if this service crashes:
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=myApp
# User=pi
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after `enable, start` the service via `systemctl` command, I can see the app is running via `top` (the process name is `dotnet`), but now the CPU is quite high (for process `dotnet`) which is over 100.

Any idea for how the CPU rises, and is there a way to keep my process name back rather than `dotnet`?

Comment: 64 bit ARM support of .NET Core is still experimental. You might report such issues to Microsoft via the proper GitHub repo.

Comment: the .NET CORE may still not so stable though, but what is the differencies between `directly run` and `run via daemon`, which cause same app behaves differ.

Comment: could you show me the link that you mentioned `.NET CORE for linux ARM is still experimental`?

Comment: ARM32 started to be fully supported since .NET Core 2.1 just a few months ago, https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/2.1-supported-os.md

Comment: @LexLi I'm using `Linux (armhf)` which is we mentioned `Linux ARM32` 
 here, refer .NET CORE Runtime here: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup#daily-builds           the Pi3B+ have a 64 bit CPU but the Raspian only support ARM 32 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the cause is the code in `Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //my business logic code
    //balabala
    while (true)
       Console.ReadLine();
}
```

that means in deamon mode, the `Console.ReadLine()` always can read a space and cause an infinite loop, which consumed the CPU, I'm not sure how that space coming, is that .NET CORE bug?